# Typo3 and Mailformplus - form not showing

Tags: content-management-system, typo3

I have a client with an existing Typo3 site but I'm completely new to the CMS.

I need to add an email signup form. The site already has Mailformplus installed for the contact form.

I've added the plugin to the page. Uploaded an HTML template, and modified a copy of the Typoscript that (I think) is required in a new template.

The title for the form appears (from the plugin record) but none of the form elements. Not even an error.

What have I missed? Where should I look?

HTML:

```
<!-- ###TEMPLATE_FORM### begin -->
<div class="mailformplus_contactform">
###ERROR###
<form name="Formular" method="post" action="###REL_URL###" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>###LLL:legend###</legend>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="###PID###" />
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="L" value="###value_L###" />
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="###value_type###" />

        <label for="name">###LLL:name######required_name###</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="###value_name###" />

        <label for="company">###LLL:company###</label>
        <input type="text" name="company" id="company" value="###value_company###" />

        <label for="email">###LLL:email######required_name###</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="###value_email###" />

        <p>###LLL:required_fields###</p>
        <input type="submit" value="###LLL:submit###" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

Typoscript:

```
plugin.tx_thmailformplus_pi1 {
  correctRedirectUrl = 1
#  emailHeader =
  langFile = fileadmin/template/xtra/mailformplus-locallang.xml
}

plugin.tx_thmailformplus_pi1.fieldConf {
  name.errorCheck = required
  company.errorCheck = required
  email.errorCheck = required, email
}


### INFO #################################################
# BETREFF und Empfänger / Config extra von Mailformplus. #
# Mit Listenansicht auf die Contactseite.                #
##########################################################

plugin.tx_thmailformplus_pi1.default {
  email_to = simon.boak@gmail.com
  email_subject = Newsletter Subscription
  email_sender = simon.boak@gmail.com
  email_redirect = 90
  email_requiredfields = 
  email_htmltemplate = 
  email_replyto = 
  email_sendtouser = email

  email_subject_user = TEXT
  email_subject_user.value = Danke für Ihre Anfrage bei Company
  email_subject_user.lang.en = Thank you for your request at Company
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set `plugin.tx_thmailformplus_pi1.debug = 1`
2. Your setup is really missing the template-setting
3. Your HTML is missing `<!-- ###TEMPLATE_FORM### end -->` at the end of the form.
4. As of point 5 in Matengs answer: Rather than reinstalling mailformplus (which is obsolete and not maintained anymore) use [formhandler](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/formhandler/current/) which is the successor of mailformplus

Answer (score 0):

1.
Start checking the source code of the frontend output. Does it contain parts of your HTML template? (e.g. `class="mailformplus_contactform"`).

2.
If not, make sure the path to the template is correct. It is set in:

```
plugin.tx_thmailformplus_pi2.template
```

If the path is correct, the source code of the template should be displayed at least.

3.
Did the extension installation finish successfully? Many extensions won't work if the necessary database tables didn't install properly. You can check in the extension manager.

4.
Furthermore, use the typoscript object browser (in module template) to verify that TYPO3 "accepted" your typoscript setup. Make sure you are on the page where you inserted the mailformplus plugin. Use the search field for that. Maybe your modified typoscript gets overridden somewhere. [More hints on debugging typoscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654913/what-is-the-best-way-to-debug-typoscript-in-typo3-cms/6671818).

5.
If that does not help, backup your current configuration and try to install mailfomrplus from the scratch - does it work when you don't use an individual configuration ?

6.
Come back here to discuss your results.