# Typoscript: AND (&&) in condition not working

Tags: conditional-statements, typo3, typoscript

I have the following typoscript

```
[PIDinRootline=6,7,11]
    //do somehting
[end]

[PIDinRootline=6,7,11] && [globalVar = TSFE:id=1]
    // do something else
[global]
```

I only get the result from `[PIDinRootline=6,7,11]`. My && condition is not working here. What I'm doing wrong?

**Solution:**

I think it was late and I only copy and pasted the code. What I wanted to do is to query on a certain page ID and a certain language. This is the solution:

```
[PIDinRootline=6,7,11]
    //do somehting
[end]

[PIDinRootline=6,7,11] AND [globalVar = GP:L=1]
    // do something else
[end]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[globalVar = TSFE:id=1]` means: *Exactly on this page*. Therefore you might need to use `OR` because both conditions cannot be met at the same time, when assuming that PID 1 is above 6, 7 and 11, like in this page tree example:

```
1 ---
- 5 -
- 6 -
- 7 -
- 9 -
- 11-

2 ---
- 3 -
- 4 -
```

Also, you can use the *typoscript object browser* in the *Template* module to debug typoscript. More options [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654913/what-is-the-best-way-to-debug-typoscript-in-typo3-cms/6671818#6671818).

Comment: In this case T3 should stop the renderning or throw an error.

Comment: @David, in which case? I don't understand why it should.

Comment: When the condition cannot met.

Comment: I understand. But what we have here is just a logical improbability, not a syntax problem. For comparison: When I ask in PHP: `if ($x == 1) AND ($x == 6)` no error will be thrown although the condition can never be met. Additionaly, in rare cases the condition from @testings example can meet. TYPO3 only stops rendering when there are severe syntax errors in typoscript.

Comment: Have you read my answer at all? "when assuming that PID 1 is above 6, 7 and 11". No offense :).

Answer (score 1):

You have just mispell the command its written AND and not ¨&&". Didn't it throw an error in the TS-Parser? You can look at the rendering process from the website in the administartion panel.

Comment: I tried it with `AND` but it is the same result. I didn't saw any error. Where do I find the rendering process in the admin panel?

Comment: Did you try with [end] at the end? According to the manual http://wiki.typo3.org/De:TSrefConditions it should work. Just open the admin panel and you can select a few options. There is a tree for the rendering process.